# I am trying to setup apache2 with subdomains

Tags: server, apache2, webserver

rollparatha.shahrukhathar.info using this subdomain name in the hosts file as under

```
127.0.0.1       rollparatha.shahrukhathar.info rollparatha
127.0.1.1       rollparatha
<publicip>  www.rollparatha.shahrukhathar.info


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

files are in the /var/www/html/Python/ & /var/www/html/Lentrax.com/demo/

Config at

```
user@rollparatha:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ cat Lentrax.com.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

  
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias *.rollparatha.shahrukhathar.info
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/lentrax.com/demo/

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost


        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

and for the other site config file is

```
    user@rollparatha:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ cat Python.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com
        ServerName Python.com
    ServerAlias www.Python.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Python

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I want to configure these vhosts as Python.shahrukhathar.info & Lentrx.shahrukhathar.info .

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do. Do you want these these subdomains to be only accessible from your localhost (127.0.0.1), or you plan to access them from the internet?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response - I want to access them via sub-domains.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to access the domain from the internet, you don't have to edit your `/etc/hosts` file. However, you will have to configure the DNS settings of the subdomains to open your server's external IP.

You can use your existing vhost configs, but it will be better if you start clean. Disable the config files you already created:

```
sudo a2dissite Lentrax.com.conf
sudo a2dissite Python.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

#### python.shahrukhathar.info

Create a new vhost file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/python.shahrukhathar.info`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/Python"
    ServerName python.shahrukhathar.info
    ServerAlias www.python.shahrukhathar.info

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/python.shahrukhathar.info_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/python.shahrukhathar.info_access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/Python>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When you are ready with the config, you have to enable the site and restart the web server:

```
sudo a2ensite python.shahrukhathar.info
sudo service apache2 restart
```

#### lentrax.shahrukhathar.info

Create a new vhost file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/lentrax.shahrukhathar.info`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/Lentrax.com/demo"
    ServerName lentrax.shahrukhathar.info
    ServerAlias www.lentrax.shahrukhathar.info

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/lentrax.shahrukhathar.info_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/lentrax.shahrukhathar.info_access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/Lentrax.com/demo>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When you are ready with the config, you have to enable the site and restart the web server:

```
sudo a2ensite lentrax.shahrukhathar.info
sudo service apache2 restart
```

#### Notes:

- It's not required, but it's a good practice to use a different `access.log` and `error.log` files for each vhost. The default `APACHE_LOG_DIR` is `/var/log/apache2/`, so you can find your new log files there.
- In the configs, I added an alias with the `www`. I don't know if you need it, it's also not required, so if you are not going to use `www.python.shahrukhathar.info` or `www.lentrx.shahrukhathar.info`, you can remove the `ServerAlias` directives.
- You may need to change some of the directives in `<Directory>` depending on your projects requirements.
- If you are using a firewall on your server, you will have to allow port `80`. For example, if you are using `ufw` you can do it like this:

  ```
  sudo ufw allow 80
  ```